# $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 a_{n}}$, for any choice of $a_{0} > 0$. This sequence is monotone and bounded. And what its limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Hello guys any help here?

I have this sequence: $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 a_{n}}$. This sequence is monotone and bounded for any choice of $a_{0} > 0$.

And what its limit?

Comment: To clarify, your title makes it seem as though $a_{n+1}$ is equal to the product of $a_0$ and $\sqrt{2a_n}$, but your body makes it seem as though $a_{n+1}$ is merely equal to $\sqrt{2a_n}$ and that there is merely the condition that $a_0>0$ off to the side.

Comment: What is the sequence? Are you saying there is a unique $a_0$ such that this converges? Because it certainly doesn't for all $a_0>0$

Comment: $x=\sqrt{2x}\implies x^2=2x\implies x=0$ or $x=2$

Comment: Now... if you were to prove that the sequence happens to converge, i.e. by showing it is monotone and bounded, you can then note that there must be a limit and that it must satisfy $a = \sqrt{2a}$.  From here you can solve for $a$.

Comment: @ElliotG It converges for all $a_0>0$ to the same value.

Comment: @ElliotG I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the recurrence formula, we have:

$$a_1 = 2^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot a_0^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$a_2 = 2^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot a_1^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot a_0^{\frac{1}{4}} = 2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}}\cdot a_0^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

$$a_3 = 2^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot a_2^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 2^{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}}\cdot a_0^{\frac{1}{8}}=2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}} \cdot a_{0}^{\frac{1}{8}}$$

So in general

$$a_n = 2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\ldots + \frac{1}{2^n}}\cdot a_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$$

Since

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right) = 1$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}} = a_0^0 = 1$$

we can deduce that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 2$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach.

Since $a_n$ is monotone and bounded its limit exists.  Call this limit $L$.

Then passing the limit through the recurrence relationship $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2 a_n}$

we get that $L = \sqrt{2L}$.  Solving for $L$ yields $L^2 - 2L = 0$ which implies

$L = 0$ or $L=2$.  But $a_0 >0$ so we must have that $L=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, if
$a_{n+1} = (ca_n)^{1/m}
$
then
$a_n \to c^{1/(m-1)}$.

This is $m=2, c=2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 a_{n}}\implies a_{n+1}^2=2a_n\implies 2\log(a_{n+1})=\log(2)+\log(a_n)$$ Let $b_n=\log(a_n)$ to get 
$$2b_{n+1}=b_n+\log(2)\implies b_n=C \,2^{1-n}+(1-2^{-n})\log(2)$$ Back to $a_n$
$$a_n=\exp\left(C \,2^{1-n}+(1-2^{-n})\log(2) \right)$$ and then the limit is $e^{\log(2)}=2$